# Why is the Java ArrayList compatible with Kotlins List interface

Tags: kotlin

Why is this working

```
val foo: kotlin.collections.List<String> = java.util.ArrayList()
```

The `ArrayList` is not inheriting the Kotlin `List`, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `kotlin.collections.List`, among other types, is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types): during compilation for the JVM, its usages are compiled into the corresponding usages of the Java `java.util.List` interface.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this works is that the Kotlin compiler will map the Java platform-specific type (e.g. `java.util.ArrayList()`) to a Kotlin platform-independent type (`kotlin.collections.List`). Not surprisingly, this is why they are called [Mapped Types](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

The key fact to understand is that after compilation, you only need binary compatibility. If all Kotlin-code on the java platform uses the `java.util.List` interface when using a `kotlin.collections.List` object, the stack manipulations on the java engine work just fine. The same is also true of the opposite direction, of course.

As for the other direction: As [this question](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-can-java-util-arraylist-inherit-from-mutablelist/6146) points out, at least on the Java platform, `kotlin.collections.ArrayList` is essentially a `typealias` for `java.util.ArrayList`.